# Compilation customizer is not called during compilation of groovy DSL script

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to write a groovy DSL with syntax:

```
returnValue when booleanCondition
```

I want to use compilation customizers to transform this expression to a typical if return statement using AST transformations.

For this script:

```
2 when 1 == 1
```

I get exception message:

```
MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found '1' @ line 1, column 8.
```

I don't understand why my compilation customizer is not called at all?
I need it to be called before compilation so I can make it into a valid groovy code.

If the script contains valid groovy code, then my compilation customizer is called.

My code:

```
class MyDslTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String script = '''2 when 1 == 1
'''
        def compilerConfig = new CompilerConfiguration()
        compilerConfig.addCompilationCustomizers(new MyCompilationCustomizer())
        GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell(compilerConfig)
        groovyShell.evaluate(script)
    }
}

class MyCompilationCustomizer extends CompilationCustomizer {

    MyCompilationCustomizer() {
        super(CompilePhase.CONVERSION)
    }

    @Override
    void call(SourceUnit source, GeneratorContext context, ClassNode classNode) throws CompilationFailedException {
        println 'in compilation customizer'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code is not syntactically valid. A compilation customizer will not workaround that: to be able to get an AST, on which the customizer will work, you have to produce syntactically correct code. One option is to use a different `AntlrParserPlugin`, but in general I don't recommend to do it because it will modify the sources before parsing, and therefore create a mismatch between the AST and the actual source.